# Add a python flag cx_freeze to executable

Tags: python, optimization, distribution, cx-freeze, pyglet

I'm making a game using pyglet, which runs like a tortoise (~30-35 FPS) unless I pass the -O flag to python when running it (which gives me a smooth 60FPS). I'm planning on using cx_freeze to distribute it, but I need the -O flag to be used every time the game is run.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same `-O` flag when you run `cx_freeze` to generate your final build, meaning that the cx_freeze generated bytecode will already be optimized. From [the cxfreeze docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/script.html):

> `cxfreeze hello.py --target-dir dist` 
>   Further customization can be done
>   using the following options:
>   ...
>
> `-O` **optimize generated bytecode as per PYTHONOPTIMIZE;** use -OO in order to remove doc strings